# Como añadir decimales de forma automática?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Tengo una string que contiene un valor, pero este valor lo tengo que convertir en BigDecimal con decimales ya que si en la String contiene este valor "258236" y lo paso por un BigDecimal me lo sigue devolviendo igual 258236. He visto que hay formas de añadir decimales con setScale y aparte de que me sale un warning de deprecated, solo me añade ceros. Hay alguna forma de que pasandole la string con este valor 258236 lo convierta en BigDecimal de esta forma 258.236 ?

> Ejemplo si la string es 000253 el valor deberia ser = 0,253 Si es
> 258236 el valor deberia ser = 258.236

Os dejo el código con el que he estado haciendo pruebas:

```
    String entrada = "258236";
    
    BigDecimal numero = new BigDecimal(entrada);
    
    System.out.println(numero.toString()); //258236
    
    
    numero.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP); 
    numero = numero.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(numero); //258236.00
```

Comment: Es que de por sí ese número que está como string no tiene parte decimal. ¿Cómo determinás en qué posición está el separador de decimales?

Comment: Rectifico, siempre el string va a ser de 6 cifras como 000253 o el ejemplo que puse, entonces hay que determinar el decimal, en el caso de 000253 debería devolver 0,253

Comment: ¿No se te ha ocurrido añadir un punto decimal al string donde lo necesites y pasarle ese string al crear el BigDecimal? `new BigDecimal("234.345");`

Comment: @SuperG280 no se puede, porque en teoría es así como se recibe el dato y como he editado antes también puede recibir casos con 000253 por ejemplo.

Comment: Tendrías que validar cuando comienza con 0 separar la cadena en 2 sub cadenas colocas el punto y concatenas; si no comienza con 0 pones el punto en la 3ra posición y concatenas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

si siempre sera de 6 digitos se me ocurre que puedas usar [subString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) para agregar (.)al numero obtenido como String y luego pasarlo a Bigdecimal

ejemplo:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Plum{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
String str = "000253";//dato recibido


String sub2=str.substring(0,3);
String sub1=str.substring(3,6);
String salida=sub2+"."+sub1;


BigDecimal number=new BigDecimal(salida);

System.out.println(number);

System.out.println("my number es de tipo " +  ((Object)number).getClass().getSimpleName());

}
}
```

salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]